# Joomla 1.5 YouTube embed with HTTPS

Tags: youtube, joomla1.5

I am trying to embed a YouTube video into my Joomla (1.5) article.
The article is in an HTTPS section of my site.
When I use the AllVideo notation to embed the video, e.g. {youtube}mVh75ylAUXY{/youtube}, it renders an HTTP link; which the browser will not allow to be embedded in an HTTPS page:

"Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL https://www.foobar.com/index.php/sales-material from frame with URL http://www.youtube.com/embed/mVh75ylAUXY?rel=0&fs=1&wmode=transparent. The frame requesting access has a protocol of 'http', the frame being accessed has a protocol of 'https'. Protocols must match."

So my question is two-fold. Is there either (a) a way to make AllVideo plugin render HTTPS embed code (I've checked the plugin options), or (b) a completely different way to embed YouTuber videos in Joomla that will support https?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the "Classic" or "Responsive" Template instead of "Framed" ?

Just a guess when reading the Features-list here:

http://www.joomlaworks.net/extensions/free-premium/allvideos

**UPDATE:**

Ok, seems that the templates don't affect the way, the video is embedded ( I was alerted by the "Framed", but that seems not to be the issue!)

Try to edit the Extension File: \jw_allvideos\includes\sources.php

In line 268 you can change the Youtube-Url from http to https:

```
"youtube" => "<iframe src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/{SOURCE}\" ....
```

Hope that helps